# Unable to get the specific record in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using the below code to retrieve the student's information stored in the database. The problem is if i use `if` with the below code then everything works fine except i get only one teacher details related to that student and if i use `while` then it shows the whole data again and again up till the number of teachers teaching that student. Any body got the solution!

```
<?php 

 session_start();

 $value = $_SESSION['student_roll'];

 require('../includes/connect.php');

 $query = "SELECT students.firstname, students.lastname, students.roll, students.semester, students.course, teachers.firstname, teachers.teaching FROM students,teachers WHERE students.roll = $value AND students.semester = teachers.semester";
 $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

    $students_firstname = $result["0"];
    $students_lastname = $result["1"];
    $students_roll = $result["2"];
    $students_semester = $result["3"];
    $students_course = $result["4"];
    $teacher_name = $result["5"];
    $teacher_teaching = $result["6"];
?>

<h2>Name : <?php echo $students_firstname . " " . $students_lastname?></h2>
<h2>Roll : <?php echo $students_roll ?></h2>
<h2>Semester : <?php echo $students_semester ?></h2>
<h2>Course : <?php echo $students_course ?></h2>

<h2>You're enrolled under : <?php echo $teacher_name ?> & studying <?php echo $teacher_teaching ?></h2>


<?php
} ?>
```

if i use only `if` i just got this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAUGu.png

And with `while` I'm getting this output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACxWI.png

Comment: You're going to need to add a bit more information as it's not entirely clear what's wrong or what you want. Can you please show your table structure (for both tables) with example data and give an example of what you want to get from the tables?

Comment: Can you add the DB table schema and show how `students` are being related to `teachers`? I think you're missing a join table

Comment: For while loop you are getting correct data because while loop will fetch all data according to query but I'm not sure what exactly you want to retrieve like only one record or multiple records.

Comment: I'm retrieving multiple teacher records for the single student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are several teachers for one student, so one record is not enough to hold all the information. Split the query into two:

First, read and output name, semester etc. for the student:

```
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, semester, course FROM students,teachers WHERE students.roll = $value";
```

Then, query all teachers for this student...

```
$query = "SELECT teachers.firstname, teachers.teaching FROM students,teachers WHERE students.roll = $value AND students.semester = teachers.semester";
```

...and output the information  in a while loop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment here but still I'm not getting the solution. I've tried the following code upon your guidance.
<?php 
 
 $que = "SELECT teachers.firstname, teachers.teaching FROM teachers,students WHERE teachers.semester = $students_semester";
 $runn = mysqli_query($conn,$que);
 while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($runn)){
  $teacher_name = $res["0"];
  $teacher_teaching = $res["1"]; ?>
  <h2>You're enrolled under <?php $teacher_name ?> and learning <?php $teacher_teaching ?></h2>
 <?php
 } ?>

Comment: Your query is missing the "WHERE students.roll = $value" part, so you are not querying teachers for one specific student.

Comment: I have tried with that but what I'm getting is:

You're enrolled under and learning
You're enrolled under and learning

Idk why but the values in php code are missing.

Comment: By using <?php $teacher_name ?> you are not actually producing any output. Try "<?php echo $teacher_name ?>.

Comment: Oops! Why i missed that. IDK. But thanks, its working now!

The last thing i want to ask is. Is there a need to write codes for both queries completely from the start till the end ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Are you wondering if the queries are too long? I don't think there's anything you could leave out.

Comment: Alright. I'll sort out the rest. You helped a lot! :)